# Blank HTML5 Canvas after publishing in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

After finishing my animation in Animate CC '15 and publishing it, the canvas only shows the stage background color when trying to load it in browsers. I have tried everything from removing elements and changing the settings to converting all images in the canvas to symbols, but to no avail.

I have a total of 8 images in the canvas. 7 png files and 1 jpeg. And the only thing I get from the output log is:

```
    WARNINGS:
** 7 Bitmaps packed successfully into 1 spritesheet(s).
Frame numbers in EaselJS start at 0 instead of 1. For example, this affects gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay calls. (6)
```

```js
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
lib.webFontTxtFilters = {}; 

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
 width: 1300,
 height: 1032,
 fps: 24,
 color: "#00CCFF",
 webfonts: {},
 manifest: [
  {src:"http://www.mrhoward.net/canvas/img/bg.jpg", id:"bg"}
 ]
};



lib.webfontAvailable = function(family) { 
 lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;
 var txtFilters = lib.webFontTxtFilters && lib.webFontTxtFilters[family] || [];
 for(var f = 0; f < txtFilters.length; ++f) {
  txtFilters[f].updateCache();
 }
};
// symbols:



(lib.bg = function() {
 this.initialize(img.bg);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,1920,1080);


(lib.cloud1 = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(0);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.cloud2 = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(1);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.cloud3 = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(2);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.cloud4 = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(3);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.cloud5 = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(4);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.cloud6 = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(5);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.skyline = function() {
 this.spriteSheet = ss["canvas_atlas_P_"];
 this.gotoAndStop(6);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.Tween10 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud2();
 this.instance.setTransform(-46,-21.5,0.697,0.519);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-46,-21.5,92,43.1);


(lib.Tween9 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud2();
 this.instance.setTransform(-46,-21.5,0.697,0.519);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-46,-21.5,92,43.1);


(lib.Tween8 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud3();
 this.instance.setTransform(-135.5,-41.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-135.5,-41.5,271,83);


(lib.Tween7 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud3();
 this.instance.setTransform(-135.5,-41.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-135.5,-41.5,271,83);


(lib.Tween6 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud6();
 this.instance.setTransform(-30.5,-20.5,0.473,0.432);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-30.5,-20.5,61,41);


(lib.Tween5 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud6();
 this.instance.setTransform(-30.5,-20.5,0.473,0.432);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-30.5,-20.5,61,41);


(lib.Tween4 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud4();
 this.instance.setTransform(-42,-24.5,0.636,0.59);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-42,-24.5,84,49);


(lib.Tween3 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud4();
 this.instance.setTransform(-42,-24.5,0.636,0.59);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-42,-24.5,84,49);


(lib.Tween2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud5();
 this.instance.setTransform(-105,-47.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-105,-47.5,210,95);


(lib.Tween1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud5();
 this.instance.setTransform(-105,-47.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-105,-47.5,210,95);


(lib.Symbol7 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.bg();
 this.instance.setTransform(-649.9,-516,0.677,0.956);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-649.9,-516,1300,1032);


(lib.Skyline = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.skyline();
 this.instance.setTransform(-650,-516);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-650,-516,1300,1032);


(lib.Cloud1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.cloud1();
 this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.548,0.636);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,320,105);


(lib.Tween11 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Tween6("synched",0);
 this.instance.setTransform(-669.7,0);

 this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
 this.shape.graphics.f("#0066CC").s().p("Ah0AsQgEgKAOgOIAOgLIACgBIgBgBQgEgHAIgIQAFgFAPAAIAJAJQACAEABABQAJgBASgJQARgIAPgCIARgEIASgLQAMgKAQgFIAJgEIgBgBIAUACQANABAFAFQAEAEABAFQABAFgDAEIgIAHQgbAQgRAEQgJABgGACIgIAIQgIAIgSADQgRABgJACQgNADgcAOQgaANgQABQgRAAgFgLg");
 this.shape.setTransform(688.4,15);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape},{t:this.instance}]}).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-700.2,-20.5,1400.5,41);


(lib.Symbol6 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Tween9("synched",0);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-46,-21.5,92,43.1);


(lib.Symbol5 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Tween7("synched",0);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-135.5,-41.5,271,83);


(lib.Symbol4 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Tween5("synched",0);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-30.5,-20.5,61,41);


(lib.Symbol3 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Tween3("synched",0);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-42,-24.5,84,49);


(lib.Symbol2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Cloud1();
 this.instance.setTransform(0.1,0,1,1,0,0,0,160,52.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-159.9,-52.5,320,105);


(lib.Symbol1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Layer 1
 this.instance = new lib.Tween2("synched",0);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-105,-47.5,210,95);


// stage content:
(lib.howardcanvas = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
 this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

 // Skyline
 this.instance = new lib.Skyline("synched",0);
 this.instance.setTransform(650,516);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(850));

 // Cloud 7
 this.instance_1 = new lib.Symbol1("synched",0);
 this.instance_1.setTransform(1133.4,124.5);

 this.instance_2 = new lib.Tween1("synched",0);
 this.instance_2.setTransform(1416.4,124.5);

 this.instance_3 = new lib.Tween2("synched",0);
 this.instance_3.setTransform(-105,124.5);
 this.instance_3._off = true;

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_1}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]},209).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_3}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_3}]},638).wait(1));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_1).to({_off:true,x:1416.4},209).wait(641));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_3).wait(211).to({_off:false},0).to({x:1133.4},638).wait(1));

 // Cloud 1 
 this.instance_4 = new lib.Symbol2("synched",0);
 this.instance_4.setTransform(358,91);

 this.instance_5 = new lib.Cloud1();
 this.instance_5.setTransform(1460,91,1,1,0,0,0,160,52.5);
 this.instance_5._off = true;

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_4).to({_off:true,regX:160,regY:52.5,x:1460,mode:"independent"},420).wait(430));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_5).to({_off:false},420).to({_off:true},1).wait(1).to({_off:false,x:-159.9},0).to({x:358},427).wait(1));

 // Cloud 5
 this.instance_6 = new lib.Symbol3("synched",0);
 this.instance_6.setTransform(996.4,268.5);

 this.instance_7 = new lib.Tween4("synched",0);
 this.instance_7.setTransform(1342,268.5);
 this.instance_7._off = true;

 this.instance_8 = new lib.Tween3("synched",0);
 this.instance_8.setTransform(996.4,268.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_6}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_7}]},349).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_7}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_8}]},498).wait(1));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_6).to({_off:true,x:1342},349).wait(501));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_7).to({_off:false},349).to({_off:true},1).wait(1).to({_off:false,x:-42},0).to({_off:true,x:996.4},498).wait(1));

 // Cloud 4
 this.instance_9 = new lib.Symbol4("synched",0);
 this.instance_9.setTransform(828.7,82);

 this.instance_10 = new lib.Tween6("synched",0);
 this.instance_10.setTransform(1330.5,82);

 this.instance_11 = new lib.Tween11("synched",0);
 this.instance_11.setTransform(639.3,83.9);
 this.instance_11._off = true;

 this.instance_12 = new lib.Tween5("synched",0);
 this.instance_12.setTransform(828.7,82);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_9}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_10}]},399).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_11}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_12}]},448).wait(1));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_9).to({_off:true,x:1330.5},399).wait(451));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_11).wait(401).to({_off:false},0).to({_off:true,x:828.7,y:82},448).wait(1));

 // Cloud 3
 this.instance_13 = new lib.Symbol5("synched",0);
 this.instance_13.setTransform(686.5,195.5);

 this.instance_14 = new lib.Tween8("synched",0);
 this.instance_14.setTransform(1435.5,195.5);
 this.instance_14._off = true;

 this.instance_15 = new lib.Tween7("synched",0);
 this.instance_15.setTransform(686.5,195.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_13}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_14}]},415).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_14}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_15}]},432).wait(1));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_13).to({_off:true,x:1435.5},415).wait(435));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_14).to({_off:false},415).to({_off:true},1).wait(1).to({_off:false,x:-135.5},0).to({_off:true,x:686.5},432).wait(1));

 // Cloud 2
 this.instance_16 = new lib.Symbol6("synched",0);
 this.instance_16.setTransform(465,314.5);

 this.instance_17 = new lib.Tween10("synched",0);
 this.instance_17.setTransform(1346,314.5);
 this.instance_17._off = true;

 this.instance_18 = new lib.Tween9("synched",0);
 this.instance_18.setTransform(465,314.5);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_16}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_17}]},629).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_17}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_18}]},218).wait(1));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_16).to({_off:true,x:1346},629).wait(221));
 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_17).to({_off:false},629).to({_off:true},1).wait(1).to({_off:false,x:-46},0).to({_off:true,x:465},218).wait(1));

 // background
 this.instance_19 = new lib.Symbol7("synched",0);
 this.instance_19.setTransform(650,516);

 this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_19).wait(850));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(650,516,1300,1032);

})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss;
```

```html
<head>
<title>canvas</title>
<!-- write your code here -->


<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mrhoward.net/canvas/canvas.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
 // --- write your JS code here ---
 
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 images = images||{};
 ss = ss||{};

 var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
 loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
 loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
 loader.loadFile({src:"http://www.mrhoward.net/canvas/img/canvas_atlas_P_.json", type:"spritesheet", id:"canvas_atlas_P_"}, true);
 loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
 if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
 var queue = evt.target;
 ss["canvas_atlas_P_"] = queue.getResult("canvas_atlas_P_");
 exportRoot = new lib.howardcanvas();

 stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
 stage.addChild(exportRoot);
 stage.update();

 createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

</script>

<!-- write your code here -->

</head>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4;margin:0px;">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="1032" style="background-color:#00CCFF"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: How are you testing this? SpriteSheets need JSON to load, and won't work without a same-domain server out of the box. Note that Animate should use a local IP, which should be fine.

Comment: Also, are you seeing errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Lanny I'm simply publishing them to a local folder and running the html in a browser. With all needed files in place, including the JSON file, I figured it would work before incorporating it into a project that i'm working on.

Comment: I have added the code and uploaded the required files to a server.

Comment: Are you just running the file locally (without a server)? This will not work in most browsers, as JSON requires a server to load.

Comment: I have uploaded to a server and several elements are missing from the canvas for some reason. I'm assuming that maybe some of the image paths are incorrect. I'm lost for any other solutions.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there were no errors. I was able to get it working. But keeping it responsive while preserving the quality seemed to be a bit of a challenge. I have decided to move away from it for a while and work on other projects. thank you for the help @Lanny

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have experienced the same thing recently, mine is more of the images not showing up, but the animation is on. If that is the case, you can try to recheck both Quality and Resolution under Texture Publishing Options then publish again. Usually 8bit with 2.0 or 32bit with resolution 3.O. Let me know if there is any luck.

However, I am still trying to figure out why the output/publishing quality is constantly changing each time and why it requires constant reset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91DE3.png)